# Java 9 Modules Example - Not function in newer IntelliJ, and how with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to understand the modularization system which came with `Java 9`, I have to use now `Java 11`, some time later switch to `Java 17` or higher.

I found this simple example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZogBPXNy3uU which shows it in `IntelliJ`, but it's from 2017 and the `IntelliJ` version is older then mine (`2021.3.2`).

I see some visual differences when creating that example in my `IntelliJ`... when opening the `Projects` sidebar I see also the project name (`java-modules` in my case I called the empty project), both modules from the example are listed below it, if this is a significant difference.

In `Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules` I see also the `java-modules` as a module besides the two seen in the example video.

The problem that I have now is, that I cannot run the `main()` method, the options `Run 'Component.main()'` and `Debug 'Component.main()'` are grayed out.

My questions: 
How to fix this example to run it? \

Comment: I just updated IntelliJ IDEA to 2022.2.3, and repeated that example... not sure if I did something wrong with the 2021.3.2 version, but now it runs as seen in the YouTube video. Still I don't know how to modify it so it uses Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in my comment it functions after the IntelliJ update.